# How to change text if url is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried searching for this question but couldn't find an answer.

My intention is to change the text that is wrapping the href link. For example

I have this snippet of code.

```
    <div class="change-this">
        <a href="http://example.com/login.php">Sign in</a> or 
        <a href="http://example.com/login.php?action=create_account" >Create an account</a>
    </div>
```

**I want to change 'Create an Account' to 'New user' and want to change 'Sign In' to 'Log In'.**
How can i achieve this by grabbing the URL and changing the text based on the URL within this div.

I was thinking of something like this.. But this doesn't work.

```
 $('.change-this a').text(function(i, oldText) {
    return oldText === 'Create an Account' ? 'New User' : oldText;
    console.log('done');
```

The reason why i have to do it this way is because the text are variables within the CMS and I can't change this but my work around solution was to do it with jQuery or Javascript. Just don't know how to implement this. If anyone can help that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: so when do you want to change it? when the page gets loaded, or when you click somewhere (where do you click to change it)?

Comment: sorry forgot to include that @Barmar

Comment: yes on page load. @caramba

Comment: Your code should work. Is it inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `Create an Account` but `Create an account`. This is the only problem.

Comment: You could also use a more specific selector: `$(".change-this a:contains(Create an account)"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var txt = $('div.change-this a');
            txt.first().text('Log In');
            txt.next().text('New User');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="change-this">
        <a href="http://example.com/login.php">Sign in</a> or 
        <a href="http://example.com/login.php?action=create_account" >Create an account</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked!! thanks @robert i should have asked if someone knew of a better way of doing this! thanks man!

Comment: @BeEasy looks like Robert helped you with this answer. You should mark it as the right answer, so it's kind a closed question.. (maybe even upvote it)

Answer (score 1):

Could use the attribute contains selector based on the `href` url?

```
$(".change-this a[href*='action=create_account']").text("New User");
```